# Laravel compressing javascript using mix.scripts(); renames function in compressed file

Tags: javascript, laravel, webpack

I am compressing a js file like this:

```
mix.scripts('resources/assets/js/pages/login.js', 'public/js/login.js');
```

My pre-compressed file contains this function:

```
function zoomInForm() { 
$('#login-page').toggleClass('zoom animated'); 
........ ........ 
}
```

But in my compressed file the function `zoomInForm` is renamed so I can never call the `zoomInForm();` function on my page.

How can I just compress a js file to one line without removing functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prevent function from being renamed. You can pass uglify options into mix options.

```
mix.options({
  uglify: {
      "mangle": {
        "except": ["zoomInForm"]
      }
    }
});
```

Maybe it can help,but maybe there something wrong with your whole script at all, even double declaring same function, just a guess...

Or try declaring a function the other way:

```
var zoomInForm = function(){...}
```

Then call it when you need with zoomInForm() later in the script and see whats happening.

Answer (score 2):

If the minifier renames the function, it also renames every place that you call it within the JS files.

Generally, you should **NEVER** have JavaScript outside of your JS files. Not in a script tag, not in an onclick attribute.

If you want to fx. listen to button click, you should create the listener in the JS:

```
$('#login-page').click(function(){
    zoomInForm();
);
```

While `cssBlaster21895` provides you with a real solution to your specific problem, I believe a more correct solution would be to move your JavaScript logic to your JS files.

Comment: Yea I understand that is a good practise to keep JS inside the file. But in this case its only a page specific JS file so I wont include it in any other page. What I was trying to do was to declare a function that animates my form when I got a validation error from the backend. So if I had a validation error I would fire that JS function to show a animation. I also have clientside validation so this was just in case

Comment: Even though It's only in one page, you should have it in the JS as-well. You can put a check to only run it, if a specific element is present.